# Tree.js raycaster не работает

Tags: javascript, three.js

Написал свой FPS контроллер и теперь пробую сделать простой collision detect.

```
var b = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

function detectCollision()
{
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();
    raycaster.set(playerBody.position, b);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);

    if(intersects.length > 0)
    {
        intersects[0].object.material.color.set(0x000000);
        console.log('Yay!');
    }
}
```

Реагирует только на линию, которую отрисовываю для проверки правильности выпущенного луча. Реакция на остальные объекты была, но в совершенно рандомном месте. Перерыл весь интернет вчера, но так и не понял в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело.

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавьте еще вектора, исходящие из позиции playerBody.position. Сейчас у вас только один var b = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), а нужен массив векторов, направленных в оставшиеся стороны. Далее перебирайте их в цикле и подставляйте raycaster.set(playerBody.position, b);
2. Убедитесь что массив "objects" содержит объекты, которые должны участвовать в коллизии.